# SQL Find the daily maximum units from a table which stores transactions

Tags: sql, presto

I have an SQL Table which stores the units (inventory) of items at any given timestamp. Any transaction(add/delete) on an item basically updates this table with the new quantity and the timestamp of occurrence.

```
update_timestamp  item_id  units
  1637993217       item1     3
  1637993227       item2     1
  1637993117       item1     2
  1637993237       item1     5
```

I need to fetch the daily maximum units for every item from this table.

The query I am using is something similar to this :

```
SELECT date_format(from_unixtime((CAST(update_timestamp AS BIGINT))/1000),'%Y-%m-%d') AS day,
item_id,
MAX(units) as max_units
from Table
group by item_id, day;
```

which gives an output like:

```
   day         item_id    max_units
2021-11-23      item1         5
2021-11-24      item1         6
2021-11-23      item2         3
....
....
```

However when generating the output, I also need to account for the units carrying forward from the balance of the transaction previous to my current day.
**Example** : For item1, there were few transactions on day `2021-11-24` and the quantity at the end of that day was `6`. Now if the next transaction(s) on this item occurred only on `2021-11-26`, and say were in the following sequence for this date : `[ 4, 2, 3 ]`. Then `6` should continue to be the maximum units of the item for the days `2021-11-25` and `2021-11-26` as well.

I am stuck here and unable to get it working through SQL. Currently how I am approaching this is by fetching the last transaction for every day separately, and then using python scripts to forward-fill this data for next days, which is not clean and scalable in my case.

I am running queries on Presto SQL engine.

Comment: What if for `item1` there was a record for `2021-11-23` with `max_units` equal to `10`, then row for `2021-11-26` should be `10` or `6`?

Comment: @GuruStron For your example, `2021-11-26` would have max as `6`. As for every day, we shall look back only the most recent record which does not belong to the current day.    

Also another thing is that all transactions for an item are sorted by timestamps, and associated with an increasing `S-No` value.    I was thinking if we can use this `S-No` column to get the just previous record to the current day -> Basically something like `S-No of the first record of the day - 1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag` window function to get previous value and select maximum between it and current one:

```sql
WITH dataset (update_timestamp, item_id, units) AS (
    VALUES (timestamp '2021-11-21 00:00:01', 'item1', 10),
        (timestamp '2021-11-23 00:00:02', 'item1', 6),
        (timestamp '2021-11-23 00:00:03', 'item2', 1),
        (timestamp '2021-11-24 00:00:01', 'item1', 2),
        (timestamp '2021-11-24 00:00:04', 'item1', 5)
)
SELECT item_id,
    day,
    coalesce( -- greatest will return NULL if one of the arguments is NULL so fallback to "current"
        greatest(
            max_units,
            lag(max_units) over (
                partition by item_id
                order by day
            )
        ),
        max_units
    ) as max_units
FROM (
        SELECT item_id,
            date_trunc('day', update_timestamp) day,
            max(units) as max_units
        FROM dataset
        GROUP BY item_id,
            date_trunc('day', update_timestamp)
    )
```

Output:

| item_id | day | max_units |
| --- | --- | --- |
| item2 | 2021-11-23 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| item1 | 2021-11-21 00:00:00.000 | 10 |
| item1 | 2021-11-23 00:00:00.000 | 10 |
| item1 | 2021-11-24 00:00:00.000 | 6 |

Answer (score 0):

I think my answer is really close to Guru's. I made an assumption that you might need to fill in dates that were missing, so created a calendar table - replace with whatever you want.

This was written in BigQuery, so not sure if it will compile/execute in Presto but I think they are syntactically close.

```
   with transactions as (
        select cast('2021-11-17' as date) as update_timestamp, 'item1' as item_id, 3 as units union all
        select cast('2021-11-18' as date), 'item2', 1 union all
        select cast('2021-11-18' as date), 'item2', 5 union all
        select cast('2021-11-20' as date), 'item1', 2 union all
        select cast('2021-11-20' as date), 'item2', 3 union all
        select cast('2021-11-20' as date), 'item2', 2 union all
        select cast('2021-11-20' as date), 'item1', 10 union all
        select cast('2021-11-24' as date), 'item1', 8 union all
        select cast('2021-11-24' as date), 'item1', 5
    ),
    
    some_calendar_table AS (
        SELECT cast(d as date) as cal_date
        FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2021-11-15', '2021-11-30', INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS d 
    ),

    daily_transaction_max as (
        SELECT update_timestamp AS transaction_date,
        item_id,
        MAX(units) as max_value
        from transactions
        group by item_id, transaction_date
    )


  select cal.cal_date
  , t.item_id
  , mt.max_value as max_inventory_from_this_dates_transactions
  , greatest(coalesce(mt.max_value, 0), coalesce(last_value(mt.max_value ignore nulls) over(partition by t.item_id 
        order by cal.cal_date 
        rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
  , 0)) as max_daily_inventory
  from some_calendar_table cal
  cross join (select distinct item_id from daily_transaction_max) t
  left join daily_transaction_max mt
    on mt.transaction_date = cal.cal_date
    and mt.item_id = t.item_id
  order by t.item_id, cal.cal_date
```